# How to split a string taken from a url in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to send a value directly in URL, in this form:

```
http://example.com/component/july2021
```

and want to extract `july2021` from the component and split them "july" and "2021"

What approach should I follow

Comment: What did you try so far? Could you share code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split() on your strings.

```
let url = window.location.href
let urlArray = url.split('/')
let data = urlArray[urlArray.length-1]
let dataValues = data.split(/([0-9]+)/)
```

Comment: is their any way I can send june2021 without queryparam but as /june2021

Comment: Yes, you just need to make sure your backend is set up for that.